# generate-id() for element if @id doesn't exist for table of contents XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Given:

```
<levelledPara><title>Tools List and Tool Illustrations</title>
<levelledPara><title>General</title>
<levelledPara><para>The special tools, fixtures, and equipment needed.</para></levelledPara>
```

I need to include the first level title of the levelledPara in my Table of Contents (so just "Tools List and Tool Illustrations" will appear.) I want to generate an @id for the first levelledPara if the id doesn't exist so I can link it to the page number. The dmcode is needed for the link. It's not working as I'd hoped, the id is generating but the page number is not resolving.

```
<xsl:template match="levelledPara" mode="tocdm">
    <xsl:if test="title and not(parent::levelledPara)">
        <xsl:variable name="id">
                <xsl:call-template name="para.id"/>
         </xsl:variable>
         <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:variable name="dmcode"><xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::dmodule/identAndStatusSection/dmAddress/dmIdent/dmCode"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lpcode"><xsl:value-of select="$dmcode" /><xsl:value-of select="$id"/></xsl:variable>
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table.cell.padding1" number-columns-spanned="2">
            <fo:block  text-align-last="justify" text-indent="21mm">
                            <xsl:number count="levelledPara" from="content" level="multiple" format="1.1.1.1.1"/>
                            <xsl:text>&#160;&#160; </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="title" /><fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"/><fo:basic-link><xsl:attribute name="internal-destination"><xsl:value-of select="$lpcode" /></xsl:attribute><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{$lpcode}"/></fo:basic-link>

            </fo:block> 
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="para.id">
      <xsl:param name="object" select="."/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$object/@id">
        <xsl:value-of select="$object/@id"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="generate-id($object)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test="not[@id]"
```

tests if there is an element `<not>` with an `id` attribute. You want

```
test="not(@id)"
```

Comment: thank you, I made the change but id is still not being generated in link.